# Can I take advntage of multi core in a multi-threaded application that I develop

Tags: c, multithreading, multicore

If I am writing a multi-threaded C application on linux (using pthreads), can I take advantage of multi-core processor.

I mean what should an application programmer do to take advantage of multi-core processor. Or is it that the OS alone does so with its various scheduling algorithms

Comment: *If I am writing a multi-threaded C application on linux (using pthreads), can I take advantage of multi-core processor.* - Yes.

Comment: Can you please just give some hint or pointer as to how to achieve this @ ComicSansMS

Comment: This is especially easy if you use an existing multicore operating system like Linux.

Comment: sounds like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to do anything. Create as many threads as you want and the OS will schedule them together with the threads from all the other processes over every available cores.

Comment: Regarding "it is best to have one thread per core": Only if you are doing something that only does non-blocking IO or is otherwise strictly CPU bound.  You can get performance gains by going beyond the number of cores if your threads alternate between blocking I/O and computation.   I think it's bad to throw out generalizations like this to somebody who's clearly new to threading w/o providing explanation or a citation.

Comment: Does Linux have the equivalent of Windows [SetThreadAffinityMask](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) ?

Answer (score 0):

"Take advantage of multi-core" could be understood to mean "utilize multi-core."

Or it could mean "gaining a qualitative advantage from the utilization of multi-core."

Anyone can do the former. They often end up with software that runs slower than if it were single-threaded.

The latter is an entirely different proposition. It requires writing the software such that usage of and accessing computing resources shared by all cores (bus-locking, RAM and L3 cache) are economized upon and focusing on doing as much computing as possible primarily in the individual cores and their L1 caches. The L2 cache is usually shared by two cores so it falls somewhere in-between the two categories in that yes, it is a shared resource but it is shared by just two cores and it is much faster than the resources shared by all cores.

This is at the implementation level, writing and testing the code.

The decisions made at earlier stages - specifically the system's software architecture phase - are usually much more important to the system's long-term quality and performance.

Some posts: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12846106/parallel-code-bad-scalability/12849275) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1081365/which-is-more-efficient-more-cores-or-more-cpus/9818992) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3647444/the-state-of-programming-and-compiling-for-multicore-systems/9517259). There are many more.